# Problems when using EF Reverse POCO Generator generated models

Tags: asp.net

I'm using asp.net default membership provider to create a website. 
I used 'EF Reverse POCO Generator' and got some csharp code of build-in membership tables, I removed some classes and kept only Applications, Memberships, Profiles, Roles and Users. 
The problem is I cannot use them because of exceptions throwing when the database is initialized.
The first exception I encountered is complaining missing the primary key, I added [Key] annotation to the primary field, problem solved.

Then I got the second error seems complaining missing foreign keys:

*Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'GoHome.Models.Memberships' and 'GoHome.Models.Users'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.*

Looks like can be solved by adding [ForeignKey], but after that I still got the third one, which I cannot find a solution in Google:

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.RolesUsers_dbo.Users_Users_UserId' on table 'RolesUsers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*

Quite odd, as looks to me there is no table called 'RolesUsers' at all.

I only added two [ForeignKey] in Memberships and Profiles respectively, which resulted in the third error. Here is the code:

```
// Memberships
public class Memberships
{
    //[ForeignKey("Applications")]
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; } // ApplicationId
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } // UserId (Primary key)
    public string Password { get; set; } // Password
    public int PasswordFormat { get; set; } // PasswordFormat
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; } // PasswordSalt
    public string Email { get; set; } // Email
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; } // PasswordQuestion
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; } // PasswordAnswer
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; } // IsApproved
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; } // IsLockedOut
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } // CreateDate
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; } // LastLoginDate
    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; } // LastPasswordChangedDate
    public DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; } // LastLockoutDate
    public int FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; } // FailedPasswordAttemptCount
    public DateTime FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart { get; set; } // FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart
    public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; } // FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount
    public DateTime FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowsStart { get; set; } // FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowsStart
    public string Comment { get; set; } // Comment

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; } //  MembershipApplication
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; } //  MembershipUser
}

// Profiles
public class Profiles
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } // UserId (Primary key)
    public string PropertyNames { get; set; } // PropertyNames
    public string PropertyValueStrings { get; set; } // PropertyValueStrings
    public byte[] PropertyValueBinary { get; set; } // PropertyValueBinary
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; } // LastUpdatedDate

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; } //  UserProfile
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use this article about migrating SqlMembershipProvider accounts to the new tables and got an error with column "FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowsStart" on "dbo.Memberships"
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/16/migration-for-user-accounts-from-the-sqlmembershipprovider-to-the-universal-providers.aspx